# Orchard Core media management permissions

Tags: orchardcms

I'm trying to set permissions for editing media gallery items from the UI. When giving the Author a permission to edit own media only I'm still able to delete media of other users in the gallery, which is undesirable. Also I have noticed there's no info in the media gallery on the ownership of media items, which seems rather strange to me.